# Tinymce add link popup

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am using tinymce editor for one of my project. Everything works fine, but I just need to change behavior of add link popup.

Actually, requirement is such that when a user clicks on addlink button from the editor, the popup window should be placed at specific place say 500px from top and 500px from left, that too of specific size ie 600*600 only.

Also one more problem is when you are in full-screen mode( by pressing F11), the popup window, is of full width and height as that of screen( specifically on mozzila), whereas I need that popup of size 600*600 overlapping the main window. Now it opens a new tab in full-screen mode.

I looked into code of tinymce, but didn't get the file, where to customize the code.
I am using basic link popup.

Here is my initialization code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        tinyMCE.init({mode : "specific_textareas",
                    theme : "advanced",
                    editor_selector : "elm1", 
                    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,bullist,numlist,|,link,unlink",
                    theme_advanced_buttons2 :"",
                    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                    width: "100%",
                    skin : "cirkuit", 
                    relative_urls : false, 
                    convert_urls : false ,
                    oninit : "setPlainText",
                    plugins : "paste,style",
                    paste_remove_spans: true,
                    paste_remove_styles: true,
                    paste_strip_class_attributes: "all",
                    inline_styles : false,
                    content_css:"<?php echo base_url("assets/css/tiny_mce/custom_content.css");?>"
                });
     </script>
```

Any help for this??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question but finally, I Solved the issue, I got to know with the plugin 'inlinepopups', and it solved the issue.

-- Thanks